# International and overall stock market chart (on Yahoo Finance)

Tags: market-indexes, yahoo-finance, chart

When I search the web for overall stock market chart I get *Dow Jones U.S. Total Stock Market Index*, which is US only. I search a global overall stock market chart (China and all other regions included).

Because I use the Yahoo Finance API, the data should be available there.

Answer (score 1):

A proxy for the global market that a lot of financial entities use is the MSCI ACWI IMI which covers ~3000 stocks in ~50 countries. Since it is an MSCI product you may not be able to pull the actual index data but you can pull the related ETF with the ticker ACIM

Comment: Can you please link the Yahoo Finance page?

Comment: @Josefine really? You should try putting in a little more effort... https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ACWI/history?p=ACWI